# Updating column values as per our format

Tags: mysql

There are two types of records in my Db such as `MS-NW` and `CS` in the same column of table DICIPLINE **I want to** wrap if its `CS` (ANY TWO STRING LIKE CS,TE OR THE LIKE) then wrap it to BS(CS) (OR BS(TE) ETC) or if its `MS-NW` (Or MS-CS, MS-TE and the like) then wrap it to MS(NW) from the column dicipline.

I updated for two strings successfully and following is the query for that kindly let me know how can i do it for values like `MS-NW OR MS-CS` and convert it to the format like  `MS(NW)` from following query .

```
UPDATE DEG set DICIPLINE =  concat("BS(",DICIPLINE,")") where CHAR_LENGTH(DICIPLINE) = 2
```

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: Who is anonymously downvoting the question? Looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: @SalmanA ummm is there anything wrong with my question? I am surprised that why i got downvotes

Comment: @SalmanA I downvote because the 1st part complete unclean.  what is CS MS-MW ? TE and other, only reading answer it possible to understand what probably was asked.

Comment: @eicto okay i'll be careful next time while asking a question and try to make my question more understandable. Thanks,

Comment: @eicto: at least two people were able to make sense of the question :) it took time, yes.

Comment: @SalmanA so your telepathy skill better than mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below query helps you to update your data.

```
update deg set DISIPLINE = if(length(DISIPLINE)= 2,concat('BC(',DISIPLINE,')')
                                     ,concat('MS(',substr(DISIPLINE, 4,4),')'));
```

[See Sqlfiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4a3e/1)

Answer (score 1):

For safety, create a temporary column of same type and perform an update like this:

```
UPDATE deg
SET dicipline_temp = CASE
    WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(dicipline) = 2
        THEN CONCAT('BS(', dicipline, ')')
    WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(dicipline) = 5 AND SUBSTRING(dicipline, 3, 1) = '-'
        THEN CONCAT(REPLACE(dicipline, '-', '('), ')')
END
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(dicipline) = 2 OR (CHAR_LENGTH(dicipline) = 5 AND SUBSTRING(dicipline, 3, 1) = '-')
```

If results are acceptable, update the actual column.